# inline-block и vertical-align

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Проблема заключается в том что, не понятно как работает свойство **vertical-align**.

Тут пример:

```css
div
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:5px;
}
div.main
{
    padding:10px;
}
.first
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.second
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.third
{
    width:110px;
    height:50px;
}
.four
{
    width:110px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
Hello world!
  <div class="first">Hello world 1! Hello world 1! Hello world 1!</div>
  <div class="second">Hello world 2!</div>
  <div class="third">Hello world 3!</div>
  <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

Как можно увидеть блоки идут в ряд как и требуется от `display:inline-block;`
Но нужно же как-то задать выравнивание этих блоков: выровнять по верху, по низу, по середине. И тут нам должно помочь свойство **vertical-align**, т.к свойство `display:inline-block;`дает нам природу **inline** объектов. Но не тут то и было проблема заключается в том что если блок и является **inline-block** то если внутри будет какой-то текст то выравнивание будет равняться по этому тексту, а не по блоку.

Объясните мне как работает **vertical-align** при **inline-block**.

Как игнорировать содержимое (текст) внутри **inline-block** элемента?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть выравнивание по тексту, есть по блоку. По-умолчанию, `vertical-align: baseline`. `baseline` - означает линию текста внутри инлайнблока.

Если вам это не нужно, ставьте `vertical-align` с другим значением: Остальные свойства типа `top`, `middle`, `bottom` никак не зависят от содержимого блока и выравниваются по границам элементов.

В отличие от таблиц, `vertical-align` назначается на сам элемент, а не на родитель.

Смотрите разные свойства `vertical-align` в моем сниппете:

```js
$('a').click(function(){$('.main > div').css("vertical-align",$(this).data("align"))})
```

```css
div
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:5px;
}
div.main
{
    padding:10px;
}
.first
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.second
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.third
{
    width:110px;
    height:50px;
}
.four
{
    width:110px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
Hello world!
  <div class="first">Hello world 1! Hello world 1! Hello world 1!</div>
  <div class="second">Hello world 2!</div>
  <div class="third">Hello world 3!</div>
  <div class="four"></div>
</div>


<a href="javascript:;" data-align="baseline">baseline</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-align="top">top</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-align="bottom">bottom</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-align="middle">middle</a>
```

Comment: С этими значениями у свойства `vertical-align` знаком, но ваш ответ не отвечает на мои вопросы

Comment: @MaximPro На какой именно вопрос не отвечает?

Comment: Хотя бы на первый =)

Comment: "_Объясните мне как работает vertical-align при inline-block._"?

Comment: Да.............

Comment: @MaximPro А что конкретно вам не понятно?

Comment: Ну допустим почему выравнивание идет по тексту? А не по самому блоку?

Comment: По моему, этот ответ в точности отвечает на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Есть выравнивание по тексту, есть по блоку. По-умолчанию, по тексту (`baseline`). Если вам это не нужно ставите `vertical-align` с другим значением.

Comment: Конечно ваш ответ не исчерпывающий, но мне кажется я понял вас. =)

Answer (score 1):

Сравнение свойств "display" наглядно показано тут http://htmlbook.ru/css/display  . На сколько я знаю "vertical-align" корректно работает только для таблиц, к сожалению. В остальных случаях придётся использовать padding/margin или js

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что некропост. Однако, ответ, думаю, будет полезным. Вместо `inline-block` для выравнивания содержимого (в т.ч. простого текста без тегов) можно использовать:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Прочие вариации я подсматриваю здесь https://itchief.ru/html-and-css/flexbox